# Can´t compile Mesa, x.org

Tags: compiler-errors, llvm, xorg, mesa

I want to install X window on my new operating system. I made my operating system with the Linux kernel and grub. My test program /sbin/init works fine. I want to install x.org (window manager) to my new operating system. X.org uses the Mesa Library (graphic library). All depencies are installed, but compiling the Mesa library failed:

./configure output

https://pastebin.com/ikPeuvBF

```
./configure: line 6973: External.*some_variable: command not found
llvm-config: error: libLLVM-6.0.so is missing
```

make output

https://pastebin.com/hpakgEni

It says that i don´t have libLLVMm. that is not true:

```
root@Ubuntu-desktop:/usr/lib/llvm-3.9# ls -la
total 56
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 jun 16 15:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 165 root root 20480 jun 16 17:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 jun 16 15:40 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 jun 16 15:40 build
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 jul 26  2017 cmake -> lib/cmake/llvm
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 jun 16 15:40 include
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 12288 jun 16 15:40 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 jun 16 15:40 libexec
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 jun 16 15:40 share
root@Ubuntu-desktop:/usr/lib/llvm-3.9# sudo apt install llvm-3.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
llvm-3.9 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqpdf13 linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Can anyone tell why this is happend. Thanks!

Comment: `libLLVM-6.0.so` is provided by the package `llvm-6.0-dev` : Only available with Ubuntu **18.04** . I.e. if you want to build "latest version of mesa", then "latest OS version" is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Knud Larsen said in the comments was the answer:

`libLLVM-6.0.so` is provided by the package `llvm-6.0-dev` : Only available with Ubuntu 18.04 . I.e. if you want to build "latest version of mesa", then "latest OS version" is required.